# Customise cxGridDBColumn to display date calendar dropdown and data aware check box

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have the following code which addeds a Checkbox to a DateEdit control:

```
procedure TForm1.cxDateEdit1PropertiesPopup(Sender: TObject); 
var   
  AEdit: TcxDateEdit;   
  ACalendar: TcxPopupCalendar;   
  ACheckBox: TcxCheckBox; 
begin   
  AEdit := TcxDateEdit(Sender);   

  if AEdit.Tag <> 1 then   
  begin     
    AEdit.Tag := 1;     
    ACalendar := TcxPopupCalendar(AEdit.Properties.PopupControl);     
    ACheckBox := TcxCheckBox.Create(Self);     
    ACheckBox.Parent := ACalendar.Parent;     
    ACheckBox.Align := alBottom;     
    ACheckBox.Transparent := True;     
    ACalendar.Parent.Height := ACalendar.Parent.Height + ACheckBox.Height;   
  end; 
end;
```

I need to change this code so that the checkbox is data aware and attached to the same datasource/dataset as the DateEdit control. The fieldname for the checkbox will be the same as the DateEdit with 'SELECTED' concatenated. Any ideas?

Comment: The TcxDateEdit is not data aware component, there's no way to attach the check box to the "same DataSource".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer Express Editors library comes with a data aware checkbox, if you don't want to write your own composite component, use the same code, just change the class you use to create the checkbox and add code to associate it to a field using your own rules, for example:

```
procedure TForm1.cxDateEdit1PropertiesPopup(Sender: TObject);
var
  //I changed the class of the DateEdit also, if you connect to your datasource by 
  //other means, update the code accordingly
  AEdit: TcxDBDateEdit;
  ACalendar: TcxPopupCalendar;
  ACheckBox: TcxDBCheckBox;
  AField: TField;
begin
  AEdit := Sender as TcxDBDateEdit;  //just to be on the safe side

  if AEdit.Tag <> 1 then
  begin
    AEdit.Tag := 1;
    ACalendar := TcxPopupCalendar(AEdit.Properties.PopupControl);
    ACheckBox := TcxDBCheckBox.Create(Self);
    ACheckBox.Parent := ACalendar.Parent;
    ACheckBox.Align := alBottom;
    ACheckBox.Transparent := True;
    if Assigned(AEdit.DataBinding.Field) then
      AField := AEdit.DataBinding.DataSource.DataSet.FindField(AEdit.DataBinding.Field.Name + 'SELECTED')
    else
      AField := nil;
    if Assigned(AField) then
    begin
      ACheckBox.DataBinding.DataSource := AEdit.DataBinding.DataSource;
      ACheckBox.DataBinding.Field := AField;
    end;
    ACalendar.Parent.Height := ACalendar.Parent.Height + ACheckBox.Height;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: I'm getting an invalid type cast error on AEdit := Sender as TcxDBDateEdit. This is because Sender is a TCXDateEdit...

Comment: @PeteDaMeat If sender is a TcxDateEdit it is not associated with a database field, just cast it as the correct class and fix the code to get the data binding from the place it is in YOUR code... I have no way to figure it out with the info provided by you.

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you need to create a new component which includes DateEdit and a Checkbox on a panel and has its own datasource/dataset, which you connect to the DateEdit's datasource/dataset on creation.
Once you have this component you will have to implement the behaviour of the Checkbox up to your needs evtl. on the DateEdit-Events.

Regarding part with the filedname for the checkbox i didnt udnerstand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Apologies for the confusion on the fieldname for the checkbox. What I mean is, if the DateEdit has a databinding fieldname of START_DATE then the created checkbox should be binded to fieldname START_DATE_SELECTED.

Comment: Well i dont know the Tcx- components but i guess you have such an Event which gets called on binding/opening your dataset, cant you set bind the chkbox on that event to the name you generate on runtime? alternativly you can implement in your new component a connect/bind methode which internally cause both components to bind to Fieldname and Fieldname_Selected. Hope this helps you further.